# LinkedIn access to Basic Profile

Tags: linkedin-api

We have developed a signup via LinkedIn app. 
We currently get the default “lite profile” but need access to the “basic profile” 
We’ve tried reaching out to all parts of LinkedIn but to no avail. 
The links to the Partner Program Page also seem deprecated. 
Can someone please share how we can get the upgraded permissions pls?

Comment: This question is more appropriately asked at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To access any of the basic profile fields, your application must request the `r_basicprofile` member permission. Check out the field names [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/profile/basic-profile)

To access email address your application must request the `r_emailaddress` member permission with field name `email-address`

Comment: Where do we request? I guess that’s the question all along. They had a partner program but that seems to have been deprecated?

Comment: Find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions?context=linkedin/context